# Delete all/Erase all/Reset timescaledb

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

Is there a way to reset everything in timescaledb by running a query?

I've tried `DROP OWNED BY CURRENT_USER;` which throws

`cannot drop objects owned by role postgres because they are required by the database system`

Comment: Stop the database server, remove the data directory, run `initdb`, start the server.

Comment: Want to do it by running a query; yes I can manually delete all the files if I wanted

Comment: Alternatively, drop all databases that contain data.

Comment: Is there a way to instead check which objects are required by the db system and exclude from the drop owned cmd?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that with a single query, but you can do it with two statements per database. Connect to database `template1` as owner of database `xy` and run

```
DROP DATABASE xy FORCE;
CREATE DATABASE xy;
```

Repeat for all databases.